# No Such File or Directory <usb.h>

Tags: c

I tried to run a program for my k70 rgb : https://github.com/CalcProgrammer1/CorsairKeyboardSpectrograph/blob/c8e2605e42e77c013857ccee58edd8a3fe998f3d/README.md on CodeBlocks. When it included usb.h, it said Nos uch file or directory, so I installed libusb, but still the same problem...

Answer (score 4):

You need the full `libusb-dev` package to compile programs using libusb, as opposed to the `libusb` package which just lets you run them

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libusb-dev`

Fedora: `sudo dnf install libusb-compat-0.1-devel`

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install libusb-dev` (at least in Ubuntu).